# How to reference document from differnet collection to another document in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two documents in two separate collections. Say, I have document one in `post` collection and the document is

```
_id: ObjectId('63e23a258224d2ef3fea4a95')
title: 'Post title'
```

and my other document in `comment` collection and the document is

```
_id: ObjectId('63e49e6ef73fe8e6fba1461b')
userId: ObjectId('xxx')
postId: ObjectId('63e23a258224d2ef3fea4a95')
comment: 'This is a comment'
```

In my `comment` collection there are lots of document that has same postId. I also have another collections called `users`. Now, I want to get something like

```
_id: ObjectId('63e23a258224d2ef3fea4a95')
title: 'Post title'
comments: [{
  _id: ObjectId('63e49e6ef73fe8e6fba1461b')
  userId: {
    name: 'John'
    age: 50
  }
  postId: ObjectId('63e23a258224d2ef3fea4a95')
  comment: 'This is a comment'
}, {
  _id: ObjectId('63e49e6ef73fe8e6fba1461c')
  userId: {
    name: 'John'
    age: 50
  }
  postId: ObjectId('63e23a258224d2ef3fea4a95')
  comment: 'This is a comment'
}]
```

How can I achieve this? I'm using `nodejs` and official `mongodb` package

I tried searching on Google using aggregate, group keywords. But didn't find solution that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using [`$lookup`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

```js
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "post_1"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "comments",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "postId",
      as: "comments",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "userId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "user"
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$user"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

You can try it out in this [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5fpJa_OYZMg).

Be sure to create an index on `comments.postId`.

It might be worth pointing out that, depending on your use case, this could return a lot of data due to the 1-Many relationship between posts -> comments so you might want to consider separating the post and comment DB calls so you can paginate the comments.

If you don't expect many comments (i.e. it's a 1-Few relationship), you might want to consider modelling the comments as embedded documents instead of a separate collection which would make reads simpler.

Some further information on 1-Many / 1-Few schema design can be found [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) and [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this functionality inside your backend routes:

```js
const {
  MongoClient
} = require("mongodb");

// Replace the uri string with your connection string.
const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@<cluster-url>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
  try {
    const database = client.db('YOUR_DB_NAME'); // Replace with your DB name
    const posts = database.collection('post');
    const comments = database.collection('comment');
    const users = database.collection('users');

    const _post = await posts.findOne({
      _id: '63e49e6ef73fe8e6fba1461b'
    });
    const _commentsOnPost = await comments.find({
      postId: "63e49e6ef73fe8e6fba1461b"
    });
    // You can later create a function for this process and take the ID as a parameter for the function.

    _commentsOnPost.forEach(_comment => {
      const _user = users.findOne({
        _id: _comment.userId
      });
      _comment.user = _user;
    })

    _post.comments = _commentsOnPost;

    console.log(_post);
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}

run().catch(console.dir);
```